# Skipped Tests are not displayed on ExtentReports

Tags: testng, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

Skipped test are not displayed on extent reports.

I am using `dependsonmethods` and as per method extent report should display test case with log skip.
But it print skip log on previous test case.

```
   @Test(priority = 12)
void UndoRedo() {
    undoRedoCase.UndoRedoTest();
}

@Test(priority = 13)
void LockUnlock() {
    lockUnlockElement.LockUnlockCase();
}

@Test(priority = 14)
void FrameLayer() {
    layerFrame.FrameLayerCase();
}

@Test(priority = 15)
void AddImage() {
    addimage.AddImageCase();
}

@Test(priority = 16,dependsOnMethods = {"AddImage"})
void EraseImage() {
    imageErase.ImageEraseCase();
}
```

Please check image image of test execution.

Image of console 
5 test case,failed 1, skipped 1
[image]

Extent report result.
[image]

Skipped test case log printed on previous test case logs
[image]

Skipped test case is not printing in extent report.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar question but approach the issue differently.  Have an after method that works great when I explictly tell it test.pass() or test.fail(), but I am struggling to have the extent reporter catch and document a skipped test.  TestNG is reporting that full tests are being skipped, want to see that in the extent out put.

```
    @AfterMethod
public void getResult(ITestResult result) {
    if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
        test.log(Status.FAIL, MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getName()+" FAILED ", ExtentColor.RED));
        test.fail(result.getThrowable());
    }
    else if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS) {
        test.log(Status.PASS, MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getName()+" PASSED ", ExtentColor.GREEN));
    }
    else if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP) {
        test.log(Status.PASS, MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getName()+" SKIPPED ", ExtentColor.RED));
    }
    else {
        test.log(Status.SKIP, MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getName()+" SKIPPED ", ExtentColor.ORANGE));
        test.skip(result.getThrowable());
    }
}
```

An example of a single validation:

```
try {
    softAssert.assertEquals(plain1, plain2);
    test.pass("PASS: Field is edited");
} catch (AssertionError e) {
    test.fail("FAIL: Field is NOT edited");
    test.fail(e);
    throw (e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing but i have tried that code already and not working in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this issue and code below worked for me.
Define the testListener like this and then call this testListener class in your Baseclass by using @listeners(TestListeners.class) before Baseclass starts.

Note : I have used Spark Extentreport

```
public class TestListeners implements ITestListener {

@override public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result) {

Baseclass.extenttest = Baseclass.extent.createTest(result.getMethod().getDescription()).assignCategory("SkipedTest");
Baseclass.extenttest .log(Status.SKIP, result.getThrowable());
Baseclass.extenttest .log(Status.SKIP, result.getMethod().getDescription());
Baseclass.extenttest .log(Status.SKIP,  MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getName(), ExtentColor.YELLOW));
Baseclass.extent.flush();
} }
```

In your test class define @Test like below

```
@Test(description = "Test Case name", dependsOnMethods = { "Name of method on which it depends" })
```